# Can user management be handled on the front-end in an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, security, angularjs

I'm integrating a user profile into the [default MEAN stack](http://mean.io/), but I keep reading that "it's unsafe to send user data between the front-end and the server." I'm not sure exactly how to interpret this — does it mean that when a user goes to update her profile, she should be doing so on an Express template instead of an Angular one? I wouldn't expect this to be the case, as surely there are AngularJS apps that use Angular to modify user data.

Is the problem just with passwords? In other words, if an "edit user profile" Angular view used the user's password to confirm changes, would that be an example of the "unsafe" data transfer I've read about?

Comment: A reference to a resource stating "it's unsafe to send user data between the front-end and the server" would help to clarify what is the meaning. As it is, of course it's unsafe, in the same sense that a server is much safer being locked down 50ft under, unplugged from the internet and the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question about AngularJS as much as it is about security. Any front end client can be insecure. Taking steps to minimize the security risk is more of a concern here.

Since you are using web pages, it will be in your best interest to use secure HTTP for anything that might communicate with your servers. It won't stop everything, but it gets most things. This is also the method that most web sites use.

Not using HTTPS will give you the "unsafe" transfer you are asking about.

If, and only if, your network is fully disconnected from the outside world, would you ever think about using HTTP only. Your safety in a disconnected network comes from being disconnected. That won't stop anyone on your network from being able to spy the traffic that goes over it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this client-side MV* pattern, so I was confused about authentication and stuff. It seems obvious now that I've read a bit about it — you just do all the normal stuff you do to secure things on the server, and all you need to do on the client side is handle the server's returned 401 errors.